# How to access a variable from one js file to another js file, both js files are in different html file in android studio?

Tags: javascript, android, local-storage

Hi I am new to android development,

In **MainActivity.java** I have webview (refer to one HTML file in **loadurl** eg: index1.html) and button, on clicking the button, I make a call from java to js(app.js refered in index1.html ) file where I will form an object (like map structure) and assign to a variable, then I will trigger another activity(Main2Activity.java) using **Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class)**

The **Main2Activity.java** also have webview (refer to one HTML file in **loadurl** eg: index2.html) now I have to access the variable in **app1.js**(**index2.html**) that variable was created in **app.js (index1.html)**

Like localstorage in js.

What changes I have to do. Thanks in advance :)

**MainActivity.Java code given below:**

```
public void ViewPdf(View view) {
        WebView.loadUrl("javascript:getDetails()");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

**app.js code :**

```
var getDetails  = function(){
// the below variable I need to access in another js file that is in index2.html
    details = {
        date : $(".mainDate .date").val(),
        no : $(".maniNo .No").val(),
        shopNo: $(".shopNoIn").val(),
        itemDetails : itemMap
    }
}
```

**app2.js code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// the valiable that is set in app.js()index1.html
    updateBill(details);
});
```